# Google Document Viewer shows "No Preview Available"

Tags: javascript, pdf, google-document-viewer

I have used Google Document Viewer to open PDF files in my Android device.  A black screen with "No Preview Available" text is shown, instead of opening my PDF files. I have tested with sample PDF files from Google. They are working fine, but not my PDF files. Is there anything that i need to do from code side to view my PDF.

```
http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=myurl.pdf
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please give a link to a PDF that is not working?

Comment: Sorry, I could not share link. It's like https://xxxx.com/123/test.pdf

Comment: Have you fix this issue. I am also getting this issue.

Comment: Yes @ohm. The reason is; my PDF file was hosted in server with some security restrictions. Later we allow permissions to that hosted PDF file & then it works fine.

Comment: Just in case anyone else has the same issue I did. I was getting this error because I had basic password protection on my folders, to make them private during production. This was not allowing google to get access to the pdf. Once I took the password protection off the folder, it worked as expected.

Answer (score 4):

Had a file that showed this problem. Renamed it to remove blanks in the file name, updated my link and it worked. **Note** that blanks were properly HTML encoded as %20 so this 'fix' shouldn't be necessary. But, I can't argue with success. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, this seems to have changed very recently to not allow blankspace and other encoded characters in the filename. Something that is very annoying since we have been using it quite a lot and so are now stuck with a lot of embedded pdf:s that used to work but are now broken. Does anybody have a clue where to bug report this?

Comment: But in my case, there is no blank space in URL. My URL is like :
/storage/emulated/0/Download/ExamPro/file_exam_pro1666056563400.pdf

but it is still not working

Answer (score 3):

Finally solved this issue. Issue is there in url. In url I replaced %2 to %252 then after 1 week I solved this issue.

In short I want to encode query string.

```
if (Url != null && Url.contains("=")) {
    String Urll =Url.substring(Url.lastIndexOf("&Signature=") + 1).replace("%2B", "%252B");
    if (null != Urll && Urll.length() > 0 && Urll.contains("%252B")) {
        int endIndex = Url.lastIndexOf("Signature");
        if (endIndex != -1) {
            Url = Url.substring(0, endIndex);
            Url = Url + Urll;
        }
    }
    Url = Url.replace("?AWSAccessKeyId=", "?AWSAccessKeyId%3D")
            .replace("&Expires=", "%26Expires%3D").replace("&Signature=", "%26Signature%3D");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try encoding the url like this

```
    try {
            encode_url=URLEncoder.encode(url,"UTF-8"); //Url Convert to UTF-8 It important.
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewerng/viewer?embedded=true&url="+encode_url);
```

Comment: Didn't worked for me.....