# Google docs iframe - not show every pdf file

Tags: pdf, iframe, google-docs-api

I'm using in [my site](http://www.dvarmalchus.co.il) with Google docs iframe to preview PDF files and last 2 weeks I have problem preview some of them, really don't understand why some are ok.

I'm using it like this:

```
<iframe id="pdfviewer" src="http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&amp;key=AIzaSyAnlkbh2TXRyCQMMWj2LQ6EY1fdqxNHf14&amp;url=http://s3.amazonaws.com/DvarMalchus/chumash/דברים/נצבים/6.pdf&amp;embedded=true" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

I got this error - "no preview available":

[image]

Comment: The problem seems similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36963331/google-doc-no-preview-available-error). How big is your file? Are you using Chrome/Firefox?

Comment: as you see, I added key attribute to my iframe - it is drive api key. problem resolved after 2-3 hours